# jQuery find/hide matching option value from 2 select menus

Tags: jquery

I have 2 select menus with matching options e.g

```
<select id="select-one">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="select-two">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

What I need to do inside the change function is if an option is selected from either menu, hide/remove the matching option from the other list. I need to show it again when a different option is selected.

I hope that's enough info but please ask if you need any more.

**EDIT**

Sorry I missed it out but I am using the [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd personally do is add a `data-*` attribute to each of your selects, containing the ID of the other select. That allows you to make your code more generic, rather than having to mostly duplicate it with switched IDs:

```
<select id="select-one" data-select="select-two">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="select-two" data-select="select-one">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Then the jQuery code:

```
$('#select-one,#select-two').chosen().change(function(e) {
    var that = this;
    var $otherSelect = $('#' + $(this).data('select'));
    $otherSelect.find('option').show().filter(function() {
       return this.value == that.value;
    }).hide();        
});
```

That adds a `change` event handler to the two selects. The first thing it does is store a copy of `this` (the `<select>` that was changed) into another variable, so it can refer to it inside the function passed to `.filter()`.

Then it gets a reference to the other `<select>` element, using the `data-select` attribute of the element.

Now it selects **all** option elements inside that, and shows them, then filters that list down to just the one with the matching value, and hides that.

UPDATE:

If you're calling the chosen plugin on the `<select>` elements individually, you may want to move the anonymous function to a named function, like so:

```
function handleChange() {
    var that = this;
    var $otherSelect = $('#' + $(this).data('select'));
    $otherSelect.find('option').show().filter(function() {
        return this.value == that.value;
    }).hide();
}
```

Then pass a reference to that function when assigning your `change` event handlers individually:

```
$('#select-one').chosen().change(handleChange);
$('#select-two').chosen().change(handleChange);
```

Comment: Like the data- thing, nice. Don't forget about the initial state though.

Comment: @Shikyo Good point, you could just programmatically trigger the `change` event on `#select-one` to hide the option with the same value in `#select-two`. One other consideration is modifying the selected option in the other list if its value is equal to the one you just selected; not sure if that's necessary though.

Comment: Sorry I completely missed it out of my question (stupidly), but I'm using the chosen plugin http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ doesnt seem to work with that.

Comment: @OliMillington I have no experience with that plugin personally, but from the documentation for the plugin the syntax for binding a change event seems to be: `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );` I've updated my answer accordingly, but can't confirm it's actually correct.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I wouldn't hold out much hope, the plugin removes the option and select tags and repaces them completely with inputs, spans and divs

Comment: @ChristopherKenney In that case we'd be looking at an entirely different piece of code to work with the replacement elements... :|

Comment: Hmmm seems I messed up the whole question thinking that because I had used simple change functions with the plugin that this more complex one would work :-( grrr back to the drawing board then!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select-one').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#select-two').children('option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == value) {
      $(this).hide();
        if ($(this).is(':selected') == true) {
            if ($(this).val() == 3) {
                $(this).removeAttr('selected')
                $(this).prev().attr('selected', '')
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr('selected')
                $(this).next().attr('selected', '')
            }
        }
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

This should work (untested), just copy it for the second, replacing the ids of course. Needs to be placed in a function executed after the select boxes are loaded or the `$(document).ready()` function.

Oh and you need to close your option tags correctly `</option>`

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/38/ (works)

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/39/ (changes value of selected option on other select box if same as current)

Comment: thanks, testing now, that list was just an example so didn't pay attention :-)

Comment: Sorry I completely missed it out of my question (stupidly), but I'm using the chosen plugin http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ doesnt seem to work with that.

Comment: That means your html code you posted is incorrect, you need to post the post-plugin-edited code, use inspect element in chrome or firebug  in firefox to select the actual html code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select-one').change(function(e){
   var val_one = $(this).val();
   $('#select-two option').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() === val_one)
        $(this).hide();
     else
        $(this).show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select-one').change(function() {
val = $(this).val();
$('#select-two option').each(function(){
$(this).css({'display' : 'block'});
if($(this).val() == val)
    $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
```

});

```
$('#select-two').change(function() {
val = $(this).val();
$('#select-one option').each(function(){
$(this).css({'display' : 'block'});
if($(this).val() == val)
    $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
```

});
});